# Flutter: build ndk version mismatch after upgrade

Tags: flutter, build, android-ndk

My flutter app could build fine before, but after updating Android Studio and Flutter today I get the following error when trying to build:
"No version of NDK matched the requested version 20.0.5594570. Versions available locally: 21.0.6113669". 
How can this error be solved?

Comment: It seems to be Android studio problem, please try to run `flutter run` command from terminal and check that app is running or not to check issue is in Android studio side or flutter side.

Comment: this is the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157024/compatible-side-by-side-ndk-version-was-not-found-default-is-20-0-5594570/61510602#61510602

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The NDK version 20.0.5594570 can be install manually by going into
 `android studio` -> `SDK manager` -> `SDK tools`.
Select the show package detail checkbox.

You will be able to see all the NDK versions available.

More details: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk

Answer (score 7):

If this issue occurred after updating android studio to 3.6 or updating the gradle plugin or gradle wrapper, then you can simply select your locally installed NDK in the **Project Structure Dialog**

You can open the Project Structure Dialog by clicking `File > Project Structure...` or by pressing the hotkeys `CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S`

Once the Project Structure Dialog is open, go to **SDK Location** and select your locally installed version of NDK under **Android NDK Location**. Typically this is installed somewhere in your user folder then `\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\%ndk version%` at least for Windows.

[Project Structure dialog screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZCdg.png)

It's usually recommended to install the latest version fo NDK available and use that for your projects.

Comment: A small problem. AS 3.6 from February 2020 has a rather different Project Structure dialog, without the item you mention. *Check for updates* says this is the latest one.

Comment: @Gábor The screenshot I included in my answer is the recent AS 3.6 - the info from the 'about' screen shows the following info. Android Studio 3.6 Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805, built on February 12, 2020 Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Partly yes, partly no, as I found out right now. It depends on the project type. The dialog you showed appears for an Android project but not for a Flutter one for me. With a Flutter app, the accepted answer was the one that helped me, too: installing the required NDK.

Comment: @Gábor if you don't mind investigating, does the other answers in the ff link apply for flutter projects? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60413117/1099775

Comment: I think this is the correct answer for the general use of the NDK.

Comment: "For Flutter apps, First you have to open the android path as a project." See @AyTee answer's above.

Answer (score 6):

For Flutter apps, First you have to open the android path as a project.
You can do it by opening some file for editing under the "android" folder end then click "Open for Editing in Android Studio" on top.

Then you can do as @Subaru suggests:

> You can open the Project Structure Dialog by clicking File > Project
>   Structure... or by pressing the hotkeys CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S
>
> Once the Project Structure Dialog is open, go to SDK Location and
>   select your locally installed version of NDK under Android NDK
>   Location. Typically this is installed somewhere in your user folder
>   then \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\%ndk version% at least for
>   Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can update in your `local.properties` the property which point to the ndk location : `ndk.dir=/Users/Shared/develop/android-sdk/ndk-bundle`