# There is no LLDB in sdk manager in android-studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-ndk, lldb, ndk-build

I am using android studio 3.6.3 in my Manjaro Linux I am trying to run c++ in android studio for that i need LLDB I reinstalled andriod studio but couldn't find LLDB in sdk manager
[image: sdk manager ss]

i tired installing ndk side by side and got and error of NDK not configured
here's my ndk_locator_record.json logs:

```
{
   "messages": [
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "android.ndkVersion from module build.gradle is not set"
},
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "ndk.dir in local.properties is not set"
},
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable is not set"
},
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "sdkFolder is /home/rijalboy/Android/Sdk"
},
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "Because no explicit NDK was requested, the default version \u002720.0.5594570\u0027 for this Android Gradle Plugin will be used"
},
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "Considering /home/rijalboy/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle in SDK     ndk-bundle folder"
},
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "Considering /home/rijalboy/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462 in SDK ndk folder"
},
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "Rejected /home/rijalboy/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle in SDK ndk-bundle folder because that location has no source.properties"
},
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "Rejected /home/rijalboy/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462 in SDK ndk folder because that NDK had version 21.1.6352462 which didn\u0027t match the requested version 20.0.5594570"
},
{
  "level": "ERROR",
  "message": "No version of NDK matched the requested version 20.0.5594570. Versions available locally: 21.1.6352462"
 }
 ]
 }
```

i could not find any solutions for it please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You will probably need to either upgrade your gradle plugin or force that 21.1.6352462 version [in your gradle config](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#apply-specific-version). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404457/android-no-version-of-ndk-matched-the-requested-version)

Comment: thanks bro solved this issue please update your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install at least the "NDK (Side by Side)" and "CMake" components as documented on the [official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk).

I just installed NDK 21.1.6352462 and that did install lldb:

```
% rg --files -g '*lldb*'
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/liblldb.9.0.8svn.dylib
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/liblldb.dylib
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/lldb-argdumper
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lldb/lldb-argdumper
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lldb/_lldb.so
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/lib/linux/i386/lldb-server
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/lib/linux/aarch64/lldb-server
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/lib/linux/x86_64/lldb-server
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/lib/linux/arm/lldb-server
```

You may need to explicitly [configure this NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404457/android-no-version-of-ndk-matched-the-requested-version) in your IDE or build process.