# How do I state in Flutter Android that the latest installed ndk version should always be used?

Tags: android, flutter, android-ndk

Whenever I update my NDK in Flutter I get the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.1.6352462. Versions available locally: 21.2.6472646
```

I declared the NDK in app\build.gradle via:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    ndkVersion "21.1.6352462"
```

Is there a way to replace ndkVersion `21.1.6352462`, so that it will always load the latest NDK and I don't have to update the number every time I update.

Comment: I believe this will help you out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404457/no-version-of-ndk-matched-the-requested-version