# Android build failed in CI because of NDK version is not compatible, but not locally

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Probably this is not the first time you see a question like this. I'ven looking into some explanations and realized that this is related to the Gradle Plugin not downloading the default version of SDK, and since in CI you usually have a machine set up that might not have exactly the same default version installed, then it would fail.

References:

- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12440
- https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/578
- [Android: No version of NDK matched the requested version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404457/android-no-version-of-ndk-matched-the-requested-version)

My question is to finally understand what is actually goin on, I am curious about **WHY IT FAILS ON CI ONLY AND NOT LOCALLY IF I DO NOT EVEN HAVE ANY NDK VERSIONS INSTALLED LOCALLY**

So, I ran the same command than in CI (./gradlew assembleDebug), and I end up with only a warning like this (Build was successful):

```
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
WARNING: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found for android.ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found for android.ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
```

However, the same command in CI end up with this result:

```
2020-06-25T01:45:32.2616030Z > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
2020-06-25T01:45:32.3617430Z > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols FAILED
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7615428Z 
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7615773Z > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7657658Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7658080Z 
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7658405Z * What went wrong:
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7659460Z Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7659848Z > No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.0.6113669. Versions available locally: 21.3.6528147
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7660128Z 
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7660439Z * Try:
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7661003Z Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7661296Z 
2020-06-25T01:45:32.7661602Z * Exception is:
2020-06-25T01:45:32.8621953Z org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
2020-06-25T01:45:32.8622201Z 148 actionable tasks: 148 executed
```

So, I would like to understand what would be the difference, or what would cause CI to have a different behavior than my local setup.

My local setup:

1. OSX Catalina 10.15.4
2. No SDK installed
3. Android Studio 4.0

CI Configuration:

1. GitHub Actions Android (ubuntu-18.04)

Project configuration:

1. Gradle Android plugin: 4.0.0
2. Gradle version (using wrapper to make sure both commands were executed with same version): 6.1.1
3. Build tools: 29.0.3

Any advice is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is https://issuetracker.google.com/148189425.

The logic for selecting NDKs changed to make builds more reproducible. Changes were made to relax that when the NDK is only used for stripping dependencies, but it incorrectly only relaxes the restriction when *no* NDK is installed.

As to how to fix your problem, just set `android.ndkVersion` to whatever you have available on CI in your build.gradle.

Comment: thanks you so much sir. Yes, I actually was able to fix it, but was curious about the weird behavior and was looking for an explanation that finally clears all those little concerns I had. Your answer explained exactly what I was looking for, now the whole context is clear to me, I appreciate your help!

Comment: According to the most recent update on the bug it should be fixed in 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

./gradlew clean

Run above command inside android folder in react native project

The logic for selecting NDKs changed to make builds more reproducible. Changes were made to relax that when the NDK is only used for stripping dependencies, but it incorrectly only relaxes the restriction when no NDK is installed.

As to how to fix your problem, just set android.ndkVersion to whatever you have available on CI in your build.gradle